# Is my answer about the Laurent's series correct?

Tags: laurent-series

Suppose I have this question:

Find the Laurent's series of $\displaystyle -\frac{4}{3(z+3)^2}$ for $|z|<1$.

This is my answer:
$$-\frac{4}{27} \cdot [(1 - z + z^2)]^2.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) of a complex function $f$ with respect to a particular point $z_0$ is a representation of $f$ as a power series which includes terms of negative degree:
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$$
which holds in some  annulus $r<|z-z_0|<R$.

In your case
$$f(z)=-\frac{4}{3(z+3)^2}.$$
I guess that you are interested in the point $z_0=0$. Then for $|z|<3$ you should expect something like that
$$f(z)=-\frac{4}{27}\cdot\frac{1}{(1+\frac{z}{3})^2}=-\frac{4}{27}\left(1-2\left(\frac{z}{3}\right)+3\left(\frac{z}{3}\right)^2-4\left(\frac{z}{3}\right)^3+\dots\right).$$

P.S. Note that for $|w|<1$,
$$\frac{1}{1-w}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{w^k}\implies
\frac{1}{(1-w)^2}=\left(\frac{1}{1-w}\right)'=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k{w^{k-1}}.$$

Comment: thank you. But why did you include a 2, 3, and 4 next to z/3, (z/3)^2 and (z/3)^3 respectively ?

Comment: @DigiNin Gravy See my edited answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much!